# Setting watcher for child form from parent form

Tags: angularjs, watch

This is the code I have for the parent form

> 

```
  <div ng-include="'app/modules/common/layout/create-rule-header-actions.tpl.html'"></div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
  <!-- Header Attributes Template-->
  <div ng-include="'app/modules/common/layout/create-rule-header.tpl.html'"></div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>

  <!-- First row start -->
  <div class="row">
     <!-- Left Side Block:  Expression Builder for Primary attributes -->
     <span class="col-sm-9 nopadding expression-block" ng-if="createCtrl.rfc.showTree && createCtrl.rfc.attributes.length > 0" ng-class="createCtrl.rfc.fullscreen?'fullscreen':''">
        <div class="row rf-tree-box marginLeftRight10" ng-controller="PrimaryMappingController as mappingCtrl">
           <div class="col-lg-12 rf-nodes-content"  griffin-mapping-component-reorder mcr-toggle="mappingCtrl.rfc.showReorder">
              <label class="width99">Expression Builder
                 <div class="sub-label ng-binding">Configure attributes for selected channel(s).</div>

              </label>
              <div ui-tree="mappingCtrl.rfc.treeOptions" id="tree2-root" data-max-depth="5" data-drag-delay="100" >
                 <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="createCtrl.currentRule.criteria" ng-init="mappingCtrl.currentAttributes(this)">
                    <li ng-repeat="node in createCtrl.currentRule.criteria track by node.id" ui-tree-node ng-include="'app/modules/common/layout/mapping/primary-node-tmpl.html'"></li>
                 </ol>
              </div>

              <label style="margin-top:80px;">Expression Viewer
                 <div class="sub-label ng-binding">Generated expression for configured attributes.</div></label>
              <div  ng-if="createCtrl.rfc.showTree " ng-controller="PrimaryMappingController as mappingCtrl">
                 <div class="rf-nodes-content">
                    <textarea id="expressionText" class="expressionText" placeholder="Dynamic expression" cols="30" rows="5" readonly ng-model="createCtrl.rfc.expression"></textarea>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </span>
```

This is the code I have for my Child form

> 

```
     <span ng-if="(node.type == 'L')" ng-include=" 'app/modules/common/widgets/mapping-tree/mapping-logical-node.html'"></span>
     <span ng-if="(node.type == 'X')" ng-include="'app/modules/common/widgets/mapping-tree/mapping-expression-node.html'"></span>
  </div>
```

{{$root.loadMoreText}}

I would like to set a watcher on the child form for all the changes in the child form and detect the same on the parent form. I am trying to set the watcher on child form from the parent form.

Please help

Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look at $broacast, $on and emit ?

It maybe could be a better solution in your case

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

The other solution is to map a scope value from parent to child or reuse a setter from parent scope from child

Comment: can you give a small code snippet please? New to working on this

Comment: tried the $emit for this. getting $scope.on is not a valid function. Searched for it on google and people said that it was because the emit is getting fired before the directive is initialized. But this emit is getting fired as part of a watcher. How do I resolve that?

Comment: If you take a look at the doc it's "$on" and not "on"